# UGC tcdl tags not getting converted after publishing to page

Tags: ugc

I am using SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 HR2. I have used the tags in the default template building block in my template building block. So the tags look something like this in CM explorer

```
<!--TemplateBeginIf cond="showunmoderatedcomments == 'False'" -->
    ....line1
    <tcdl:Comments itemURI="@@Component.ID@@@@Page.ID@@">
        <h4> Before </h4>
        .... line2
        <tcdl:ContextVariable var="ugcComment.content"/>
        <h4> After </h4>
```

After publishing, the view source on the jsp appears as.

```
    <ugc:comments itemuri="tcm:10-11111">
    <h4> Before </h4>
    <h4> After</h4>
```

Line2 does not appear in the html. The code with ContextVariable doens't get converted.

Comment: No real answer but a few thoughts: The live documentation at http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-16331362-F60D-4916-9915-264B82CD38F5 says there is no TCDL tag for ContextVariable as it is .NET only.
And, are you closing <tcdl:Comments> properly?

Comment: Hi Jan. Thanks for responding. I can't seem to catch a break with this. I tried using  ${ugcComment.content} on my component. But it still doesn't appear on the page

Comment: Jan, can you point to a good tutorial or resource I can get help with for this. Thanks